# Access test classpath in test code

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to test code that is forking a JVM process and for that I'd need to either access `test:fullClasspath` or make test depend on `package` and use classpath with fat jar.

The later option is very hacky, slow and it doesn't contain any test binaries. As to the former solution, I cannot figure out how to access `test:fullClasspath`. No matter whether I run test in current JVM or as a forked process, `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` always gives me `/opt/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running your code from SBT (`sbt run`) or somehow else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run from SBT, that seems to work as soon as you instruct SBT to fork your application when running. Here's what I have:

Project:

```
<project root>
  - build.sbt
  - src
    - test
      - scala
        - test.scala
```

In `build.sbt`:

```
fork := true
```

in `test.scala`:

```
object Test extends App {
  println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))
}
```

Then from `<project root>` I run:

```
sbt test:run
```

And it prints:

```
/Users/username/projects/tmp/scala/target/scala-2.11/test-classes:/Users/username/projects/tmp/scala/target/scala-2.11/classes:/Users/username/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.11.jar
```

It seems the first part of that class path, i.e. `/Users/username/projects/tmp/scala/target/scala-2.11/test-classes`, is what you're looking for, right?

Comment: You are right, it was my fault. My fork global setting got overriden by a plugin that set fork to false at project level :-/